# Flux without data caching?

Tags: api, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Almost all examples of flux involve data cache on the client side however I don't think I would be able to do this for a lot of my application.

In the system I am thinking about using React/Flux, a single user can have 100's of thousands of the main piece of data we store (and 1 record probably has at least 75 data properties).  Caching this much data on the client side seems like a bad idea and probably makes things more complex.

If I were not using Flux, I would just have a ORM like system that can talk to a REST API in which case a request like `userRepository.getById(123)` would always hit the API regardless if I requested that data in the last page.  My idea is to just have the store have these methods.

Does Flux consider it bad that if I were to make request for data, that it always hit the API and never pulls data from a local cache instance?  Can I use Flux in a way were a majority of the data retrieval requests are always going to hit an API?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can sanely get to no caching is to reset any store state to null or [] when an action requesting new data comes in.  If you do this you **must** emit a change event, or else you invite race conditions.

As an alternative to flux, you can simply use promises and a simple mixin with an api to modify state.  For example, with bluebird:

```js
var promiseStateMixin = {
  thenSetState: function(updates, initialUpdates){
    // promisify setState
    var setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    var setStateP = function(changes){
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            setState(changes, resolve);
        });
    };

    // if we have initial updates, apply them and ensure the state change happens
    return Promise.resolve(initialUpdates ? setStateP(initialUpdates) : null)
      // wait for our main updates to resolve
      .then(Promise.params(updates))
      // apply our unwrapped updates
      .then(function(updates){
          return setStateP(updates);
      }).bind(this); 
  }
};
```

And in your components:

```js
handleRefreshClick: function(){
  this.thenSetState(
      // users is Promise<User[]>
      {users: Api.Users.getAll(), loading: false}, 

      // we can't do our own setState due to unlikely race conditions
      // instead we supply our own here, but don't worry, the
      // getAll request is already running
      // this argument is optional
      {users: [], loading: true}
   ).catch(function(error){
      // the rejection reason for our getUsers promise 
      // `this` is our component instance here
      error.users 
   });
}
```

Of course this doesn't prevent you from using flux when/where it makes sense in your application.  For example, react-router is used in many many react projects, and it uses flux internally.  React and related libraries/patters are designed to only help where desired, and never control how you write each component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest advantage of using Flux in this situation is that the rest of your app doesn't have to care that data is never cached, or that you're using a specific ORM system. As far as your components are concerned, data lives in stores, and data can be changed via actions. Your actions or stores can choose to always go to the API for data or cache some parts locally, but you still win by encapsulating this magic.

Comment: Well the problem is that stores from what I read should 1. only emit a single event which is changed and 2. that the emit should not pass any data with it, you should be calling the store in the callback to get the data.  If I have a page, lets say a dashboard for a project management system where I have 3 separate requests for an issue list, each filtered differently.  If I only have 1 issues store, how can I know which request finished when and if I don't cache the data, how do I get at it?

Comment: it ends up looking something like this: on the first call to store.getIssues, if the store doesn't have the data it initiates an api request and returns an empty result. Once the api request completes asynchronously, an action is dispatched, and the store updates itself and emits a change event. So, now the original caller calls store.getIssues again and this time receives data instead of an empty list

Comment: you would still have to decide whether to cache any data and how to invalidate that cache though - you could cache some data, and if the store receives a request for data that is stale, the store returns the stale data, and calls the api to refresh itself (which then dispatches an action and causes another store change event)